# Are there any good hierarchical clustering packages in python which take distance matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

I have a distance matrix composed of pair-wise levenshtein's distance. I was using scikits-learn. But hierarchical clustering algorithm doesn't take distance matrix as input for clustering. SO I have to search for a new package which can do this.

Are there any fast and well tested packages that you have used for hierarchical clustering ?

Comment: Other alternative I found is hosted at [fastcluster package](http://math.stanford.edu/~muellner/fastcluster.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.ward` function (used as backing implementation of `sklearn`'s `Ward` when the connectivity constraints are not required) can accept both observations and precomputed distance (see the [online documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.9.0/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html) for more details). It's just not yet exposed in `sklearn`'s API.